# CSS class style not applied (might be overriden)

Tags: html, css, angular

I use a external lib css (internally developped) but it is not usefull to share it.

My problem is the following :

I use angular and I have this :

testSelect.componenent.html :

```
<div class="c-input c-input--select">
  <select id="selectID"> 
    <option> bla bla </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and my testSelect.componenent.scss :

```
.c-input--select {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}
```

The fact is that the padding is not applied.

My guess is that my external CSS lib is overriding my little scss...

When I add a surrounding div like that :

```
<div class="test">
  <div class="c-input c-input--select">
    <select id="selectID"> 
      <option> bla bla </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

with

```
.test {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}
```

it is working. But I guess in terms of code cleanliness and reusability it is not good...

How should I do ?

Comment: Adding wrappers or modifier classes is not always bad, specially when you don't want to affect all elements with same class
Like u said there must be another style rule overriding your .c-input--select... Either from a later rule in your app using the same class, or a more specific CSS selector. You could inspect the element with dev tools and see what rule is being applied to the element, and share that if you're still uncertain... 
Without knowing that, all I could suggest is something like .c-input.c-input--select or .c-input--select > select to (potentially) get a more specific selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chrome developer tools to see what CSS classes are affecting your elements.

Right-click the element in question in Chrome, then select Inspect Element.  You will see every single CSS class that is affecting your element.

It is probable that you are correct, some class in your external library is affecting it.  If that is the case, you have a couple of options.

The best option is to create a specific CSS class for your entire component, and wrap the entire template in that class, something like what you suggest re: the surrounding Div, but at the whole component level.  Name it something specific to your component so there's no chance of a name collision.

Your second option is to use !important, but you really should only do this if you have no other choice.  The case where you have no other choice, is if your imported CSS library defines those classes as !important itself.  If they do that, you really have no other option, short of asking the team who maintains the library to stop using !important.